# Problem installing texlive (./install-tl: command not found)

Tags: texlive

[image]Im trying to install texlive for .iso but when i tried `./install-tl` the terminal said me `sudo: ./install-tl: command not found`

. Thx

Comment: In the folder I am writing on ./install-tl is the install-tl btw i ll upload a pic.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod +x install-tl` first and then again your command ... if it doesn't work give us the `ls -l` output

Comment: It's a Perl script so you can always just run ` perl install-tl` , which does not require execute rights on the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo chmod +x install-tl` first and then again your command ... if it doesn't work give us the `ls -l` output .

Solved by koleygr.

Comment: Nice ... remember to come back and accept the answers in a few days that it will be possible in order to help future visitors ... Happy TeXing!